# Using DB2 query to join into mysql data for insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, db2

I'm trying to get a script together in php that takes a query from DB2, using sql, and then uses that result set by equating it to data in a mysql table in anther connection and inserts results based on that into another.

Basically, My db2 query returns several fields that are needed to determine the ID of a table in My SQL

Below I have an example:

I'm selecting from here:
DB2 Query Results

```
Dealer | Style | Frame | Cover | Color | Placements | shipdate
---------------------------------------------------------------
123        1      1234    12       1         2         20180219
123        2      1235    12       1         2         20180219
123        3      1236    12       1         2         20180219
```

I need to join the former data, in a sense, to the following data in the
SKU Table (db2.style = sku.groupID, db2.frame = sku.frame, db2.cover = sku.cover, and db2.color = sku.color) in order to get the correct ID

```
ID | Frame | GroupID | cover | color 
------------------------------------
15    1234      1        12      1
16    1235      2        12      1
17    1236      3        12      1
```

Then below, I need to do an insert of the previously determined ID, as well as some of the data from the original DB2 query (insert style into groupID, dealer into dealerID, shipdate into startdate, placements into placements)

INSERT would result in:  (skuplacement table)

```
sku_id | groupID | dealerID | startDate | expirationDate          | placements
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15          1       123        20180226    (shipdate + 127 days)       2
16          2       123        20180226    (shipdate + 127 days)       2
17          3       123        20180226    (shipdate + 127 days)       2
```

I hope this makes sense.

I've included my full script as of right now, but My INSERT/SELECT/JOIN for MYSQL is missing. I'm not sure how to go about this right now, but I have both connections working. It's just a matter of creating the correct query.

I'm happy to answer any questions to clear up confusion.

```
            <?php


            //Establilsh MySql Connection
            $mysqlConn = new mysqli($mysqlServer, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass);

            //Check MySQL connection
            if($mysqlConn->connect_error){
              die("Connection Failed: " .$mysqlConn->connect_error);
            }
            echo "Connected Succssfully to Mysql";

            //Establish DB2 connection
            $DB2Conn = odbc_connect();

            //Check DB2 Connection
            if(!$DB2Conn){
              die("Could not connect");
            }else{
                echo"Connected to DB2";
            }



            $plcQueryDB2 = "

                   select
                        xcstno as dealer,
                        p.style as Style,
                        trim(p.framfmt) as Frame,
                        p.cover1 as Cover,
                        p.color1 as Color,
                        sum(skunoc) as placements,
                        p.extd1d as shipdate
                    from pieces p
                    where left(shipdate, 4) >= '2016'
                    group by xcstno, xslsno, sup, f.style, f.grpnam, f.framfmt, f.cover1, f.color1, f.coldss,a.extd1d
                    order by left(shipdate, 4) ASC, REP
                ";

            $prep = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);
            $exec = odbc_execute($prep);

            $result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);

            if(!$prep){
                die("Could Not Run Query");
            }else{
                echo "DB2 Query Successful";
            }


            while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
                     for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result);$i++){
                    echo "Result is ".odbc_result($result,$i);
                }
            }


            /*Need to get an INSERT created here*/

            $InsertSKUS = "

                    INSERT INTO skuPlacement
                    values (?,?,?,?,?,?)     
            ";

            /* This is my problem. I need to select from another table called skus and insert into skuPlacement based on equating fields from my previous DB2 query and the skus table*/


            ////*CLOSE CONNECTIONS*////


            if (mysqli_close($mysqlConn)){
                echo "MySQL Closed";
            }

            //$CloseDB2 =  odbc_close( $DB2Conn);

            if(odbc_close( $DB2Conn)){
                echo "DB2 Closed";
            }





            ?>
```

Comment: Do try and trim out endless expanses of blank lines from your code. The more compact it is, the easier it is to understand what's going on.

Comment: Right, sorry.......That was a huge oversight, I should have cleaned it up a bit more

Comment: Not a huge deal, but keeping things tidy means you're making an effort to keep things as small and focused as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider saving your DB2 query results to csv file. Then import the csv file into MySQL with [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) (a fast bulk facility) and run needed join append query all inside MySQL:

**DB2** Query CSV

```
try {
    $DB2Conn = odbc_connect();

    $plcQueryDB2 = "...";
    $prep = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);
    $exec = odbc_execute($prep);
    $result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);
}
catch(Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
} 

// Writing column headers
$columns = array('Dealer', 'Style', 'Frame', 'Cover', 'Color', 'Placements', 'shipdate');
$fs = fopen('DB2_Query.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fs, $columns);      
fclose($fs);

// Writing data rows
while($arr = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $fs = fopen('DB2_Query.csv', 'a');
      fputcsv($fs, $arr);
    fclose($fs);
}

odbc_close($DB2Conn);
$DB2Conn = null;
```

**MySQL** Queries *(run separately in PHP or console)*

```
$mysqlConn->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db2Temp (
                       dealer INTEGER,
                       style INTEGER,
                       frame INTEGER,
                       cover INTEGER,
                       color INTEGER,
                       placements INTEGER,
                       shipdate DATE
                  )");

$mysqlConn->query("DELETE FROM db2Temp");

$mysqlConn->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /path/to/DB2Query.csv
                   INTO TABLE db2temp
                   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                   IGNORE 1 LINES");

$mysqlConn->query("INSERT INTO skuPlacement (sku_id, groupID, dealerID, startDate,
                                             expirationDate, placements)
                   SELECT sku.ID, sku.Group_ID, db2.dealer, db2.shipDate,
                          DATE_ADD(
                               DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(db2.shipDate, CHAR(8)), '%Y-%m-%d'), 
                               INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expirationDate,
                          db2.placements
                   FROM sku
                   INNER JOIN db2temp db2
                   ON db2.style = sku.groupID
                   AND db2.frame = sku.frame
                   AND db2.cover = sku.cover
                   AND db2.color = sku.color
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS                  
                      (SELECT 1 FROM skuPlacement p
                       WHERE sku.ID = p.sku_ID)");
```

Comment: Wow this looks like a great answer  but I am on mobile so I will have to try to apply this In a few hours. As a proof of concept for my team, would I also be able to do something similar with an array as a substitute for the csv? I prefer this method, just trying to think of methods to apply

Comment: While arrays are hash tables for key/value pairing, they are not set-based, row/column tables like in databases. So you will not take advantage of index joins. The CSV is simply a medium to build a temp table to connect tables together in one database, avoiding nested `for` looping through all rows and checking if they are equal with other array items. Blockwise handling is usually more maintainable/robust/efficient.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm making this as a script to run regularly as a way to get new data from the old database to a new one, would it be most wise to run the first portion as a script on a schedule and make sure the 2nd portion runs after?

Comment: Also the line ```while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){``` is giving me error that it expects parameter 1 to be a resource

Comment: Yes, all can be run regularly in sequence. I updated to show how to run queries in PHP. As for the `while(...)`, I forgot to copy over the `$result = ...` line. See edit. Also, check the type of your *shipdate* as it is not in true date format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. Is it an integer or string? If so, you need to convert to actual datetime for `DateAdd()` function.

Comment: Ah yes, that was an oversight on my part, it is an integer in fact

Comment: So, I can convert that to datetime, and I appreciate your edits. I've employed those and now get an error that fputcsv expects param 2 to be array, string given. SO I think I know how to rectify that

Comment: See update using `odbc_fetch_array` instead of row and removing the inner `for` loop. And see adjustment of date calculation requiring conversion to string. Painful! Always store dates in actual datetime types!

Comment: That got it, thank you! And trust me, I will. Unfortunately we have to incorporate a lot of legacy DB2 data that wasnt created with the best standards, but we're in the process of rebuilding a lot of it.

Comment: do you know of a good way to do batch inserts with this? I have it working, and I've been limiting the results in the code but there are a few hundred thousand records and I know it will exhaust memory or timeout eventually